# SQL Server - Update data

Tags: sql-server

I have an table with this structure (example) **ORIGNTABLE**:

```
ID    IDParent
80       0
81       80
82       0
83       82
```

Then I make a duplicate of this data obtaining the following data:

```
ID    IDParent
80       0
81       80
82       0
83       82
---- duplicated data ---
84       0
85       80
86       0
87       82
```

on the other hand, with the duplication of data also get a temporary table with the following information  **AUXTABLE**:

```
OldID   NewID   OldParentID
80      84      0
81      85      80
82      86      0
83      87      82
```

So, my problem is update the new data, specifically, the IDParent. I'm failing to do this.
I pretend the final data like that:

```
ID    IDParent
80       0
81       80
82       0
83       82
---- duplicated data ---
84       0
85       **84**
86       0
87       **86**
```

Anyone can help me to update the data? i'm trying many options but none work:
*1st try*

```
UPDATE ORIGINTABLE
SET IDParent = AT.NewID
FROM ORIGINTABLE OT 
INNER JOIN AUXTABLE AT ON AT.NewID=OT.ID
AND AT.OldParentID=OT.IDParent
```

*2st try*

```
 UPDATE ORIGINTABLE
    SET IDParent =AT.NewID
    FROM ORIGINTABLE OT 
    INNER JOIN AUXTABLE AT ON AT.OldParentID=OT.ID
```

Comment: Can you specifiy also expected result since I don't really understand those "**84**"

Comment: When I duplicate the data, I get the same IDParents ace lines up, what is wrong. 
I want to replace the IDParents new lines by matching IDS. Those "84" is the correct IDParent os this line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is to join `AUXTABLE` twice. One instance will act as a filter, so that only new rows become updated. The other instance will provide the necessary mapping between old and new ID values.

[This is the query](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c4f5a/2):

```
UPDATE ot
SET ot.IDParent = mapping.NewID
FROM    ORIGINTABLE AS ot
INNER JOIN AUXTABLE AS filter  ON filter.NewID  = ot.ID
INNER JOIN AUXTABLE AS mapping ON mapping.OldID = ot.IDParent
;
```